# Zustand not persisting data in AsyncStorage correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zustand

I am trying to persist data to AsyncStorage using Zustand.

Here is my code for the store:

```
//store.ts

export const useAuthStore = create(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      token: "",
      setToken: (token) =>
        set((state) => ({
          token: token,
        })),
    }),
    {
      name: "token",
      getStorage: () => AsyncStorage,
    }
  )
);
```

Here is the code for my login page:

```
//login.tsx

  const setStoreToken = useAuthStore((state) => state.setToken);

  async function handleLogin() {
    setStoreToken("6747rt345t67324xn487r364qxuhfu");
    const storedToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log(storedToken);
  }
```

The console.log in login.tsx is here:
{"state":{"token":"6747rt345t67324xn487r364qxuhfu"},"version":0}.

What I would like to get is "6747rt345t67324xn487r364qxuhfu", which is just the token without the session and version.

Comment: can you please explain more..?, you need to compare the token of the store and async storage is it right or wrong..?

Comment: Hi @AnkitVora, the token is correct, The issue is the extra data (state and version} that I don't want to be stored. I am trying to get rid of these extra items so it just leaves me with the token only.

Comment: can you please share the code where you are storing the token.

Comment: Thats the code under ```//store.ts```. The persist middleware stores it in AsyncStorage. Here: ```{
      name: "token",
      getStorage: () => AsyncStorage,
    }```

Comment: can you please share this log ==>
 ```set((state) => ({
console.log(">>>",state)
          token: token,
        })),```

Answer (score 4):

Using `getStorage` got deprecated in the latest version of Zustand, now it must be written like the following:

```js
//store.ts
import { persist, createJSONStorage } from 'zustand/middleware';


export const useAuthStore = create(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      token: "",
      setToken: (token) =>
        set((state) => ({
          token: token,
        })),
    }),
    {
      name: "token",
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => AsyncStorage), // <==  pay attention
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: I tried this. But the value of Token gets resolved to empty string everytime the app is starte so i don't think the async storage is working properly